# Video tutorial help

Tags: video-editing

I'm trying to teach people how to use a new app.  I used to use flash to create interactive tutorials.  I can't find any tool now that allows me to create interactive screen demos.  There seem to be lots of screen recording tools but none that allow me to add interaction.  I'm hoping to publish the resulting interactive tutorial in some kind of HTML5/javascript format.  Is there anything I could use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these might help, but there's probably more.

### Most likely very expensive options

- https://www.wirewax.com/
- http://www.raptmedia.com/
- https://corp.hapyak.com/

### Not as expensive options

- https://www.vixyvideo.com/interactive-video
- https://hihaho.com/
- https://vidzor.com/